# How to solve "Empty static prefix not permitted" error in Django?

Tags: django, deployment, python-2.7, django-staticfiles

I installed Django 1.5.1 with MySQL and mod_wsgi on ubuntu. After I imported my project from local machine to the server, I get this error by visiting all URLs:

```
**ImproperlyConfigured at /**
Empty static prefix not permitted
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://50.7.177.122/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
Empty static prefix not permitted
Exception Location: /srv/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/static.py in static, line 22
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/srv/projects/app/danial',
 '/srv/projects/app',
 '/srv/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/srv/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/srv/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/srv/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/srv/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.9.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenvwrapper-4.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stevedore-0.8-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_clone-0.2.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

My project name is danial, it contains an app, gallery. My static folder located at /danial/gallery/static I'm so confused. Here's all Static related lines in my project:

```
###settings.py
STATIC_ROOT = '/srv/projects/app/danial/gallery/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/srv/projects/app/danial/gallery/static/',)

###apache setting
Alias /static/ /srv/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/

###urls.py

from danial import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

It works well on my local. What shoudl I do know?

Comment: I think your `Alias` of static doesn't match your `STATIC_ROOT` nor `STATICFILES_DIRS` path. Is this intentionally?

Comment: I've changed `Alias` of static to same address as `STATIC_ROOT`, but still get error.

Comment: have you run `manage.py collectstatic`? Or just deployed to server with static already collected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed static alias from
`/srv/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/`
 to   `/srv/projects/app/danial/gallery/static/` and removed static related lines from `urls.py` .

I just need to copy `../django/../static/admin` to `../projects/../static/admin` . Now django project works fine.

Answer (score 2):

In `urls.py`, when you use:

```
static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

you need to define `MEDIA_URL` with none empty value in `settings.py`.

And define `STATIC_URL` with none empty value in `settings.py` if you are using:

```
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Also it's work when `DEBUG` is set to `True` (During development), 
Here is the source code of `sattic`:

```
def static(prefix, view=serve, **kwargs):
    if not settings.DEBUG or (prefix and '://' in prefix):
        return []
    elif not prefix:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("Empty static prefix not permitted")
    return [
        url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % re.escape(prefix.lstrip('/')), view, kwargs=kwargs),
    ]
```